# REST API in Postman works but does not work in REACTJS App for a POST request using AXIOS

Tags: reactjs

I have this simple code in REACT which does not work but works fine in POSTMAN. That POST request is a golang backend

```
const tokenString = { userName: this.state.userName}
const headers = { 
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'
      }

  axios.post('http://localhost:10000/checkUserCredentials', tokenString,{headers})
    .then((response) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response))
    })
```

I tried using the samples provided by https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/17/react-axios-http-post-request-examples and it works fine.

I tried to debug my backend and it works fine when the call is made from REACT but the response never comes through. Both backend and REACT are on my same mac machine.

I have the following error  "Error: Network Error".

How to resolve this.

Comment: Can you tell us what what response you get from your backend. Like an error or something

Comment: What is error you are getting? Is it CORS? If yes you need to unable CORS

Comment: What is error you are getting? Is it CORS? If yes you need to unable CORS

Comment: Please share any related error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it to work, this is my 1st adventure on ReactJS hence things look very weird. I have this same app working on node.js perfectly. My intention was to transition the UI to ReactJS and its not been an easy journey. I hope its worth the effort.

Here is how I made it work

This article gave me an inspiration https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347

1. I added the following to my package.json
   "proxy": "http://localhost:10000"
2. I also had to change the POST to the following /checkUserCredentials, earlier it was with full URL.

   axios.post('/checkUserCredentials', tokenString,{headers})
   .then((response) => {
   alert(JSON.stringify(response))
   })
   .catch(error => {
   alert(error);
   });